# Automation Problem - Recursion

Tags: process-builder

I am dealing with an automation problem which I don't know how to solve and I hope to get some pointers from you. The task I want to achieve is that a certain field is filled with a code generated by an Apex-script. This should be done when the record type of a contact is changed.

Below I am describing two criteria nodes in a Process Builder. The first changes the record type and fills some fields (which are required for the filling of the field with the apex script).

In the screenshot below you can see two criteria nodes.

[image: Process Builder]

In the upper node there is a check to see if the recordtype of the record has changed

```
OR( 
    AND(
        [Contact].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Medewerker',
        ISCHANGED([Contact].RecordTypeId ) 
    ),
    AND(
        ISNEW(),
        [Contact].RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Medewerker'
    )
)
```

This is the part that works ;) The second criteria node checks whether certain fields are filled. What I thought the problem was, was that these fields are filled as an action after the first criteria node. However, when I turned on recursion this did not solve the problem. In fact, this resulted in executing the first node more than once.

Do you have any pointers as to where the problem could lie?
If any extra info/context is needed, let me know!

Comment: I am not sure what the exact problem is - meaning: I don't understand what you try to achieve and what does not worked - but I might be daft.

Comment: can you show the criteria for second node

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added an intro. I hope this is clearer.